# When adding item to array, it overrides the first value

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason when I try to add an item to my array it overrides the fist item. I can't figure out why it is doing that. The first element should have an id of 1 and the second should be 2 but instead I get 2 and 2.

```
$array = new stdClass;
$arrays = [];
$ids = [1,2];

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $array->id = $id;
    $arrays[] = $array;

    print_r($arrays);
}
```

**The result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating the same object, you need to put 2 different objects within the array, bring the class declaration within the loop.

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $array = new stdClass; // object initialization
    $array->id = $id;
    $arrays[] = $array;

    print_r($arrays);
}
```